# Displaying python topic modelling results on tableau dashboard

Tags: python, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am fairly new to tableau and I was hoping to get more clarity on the below query:

I have carried out topic modelling on python using Gensim model, I wanted to know if it is possible to display the topic modelling visualization on my dashboard

I have linked my tableau to the python server using tabpy, but I am not sure if I can go ahead and display the pyldavis results on the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your code to Tableau by creating a calculation filed and use script_string function. The output of your code needs to be a list of topics also the code get the input from the visualization so it will generate topic for any data available in the viz.